# Error connection to postgres database using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, boto3, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a postgres database to run some queries for validation. Trying to establish connection via psycopg2. Have tried passing actual values for host instead of variables.

Tried the connection using `psql` to verify the connection parameters, password etc and they are right too.
But with the code below it always errors out with the below error

```
    conn1 = psycopg2.connect(host=db_host,database=db_instance_name,user=masterusername,port=db_port,password=masterpassword)
    cur1 = conn1.cursor()
    print ('\n************Connection is successful ************ \n')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restored_db_details_draft.py", line 50, in <module>
    conn_test = psycopg2.connect(host="***",database="my_db_name",user="master",port="9876",password="****")
  File "/Users/me/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Comment: The code runs where? On your local machine, ec2 instance, lambda function?

Comment: Please try running that code from a different network (eg home vs work vs tethered via your phone). This will help identify whether the problem is being caused by restrictions imposed by the network.

Comment: Hi Marcin/John,  The issue is fixed, it was my mistake - i was running the code on my laptop and the connection was not open for the database from my machine. AFter opening of ports it works fine. psql which i was checking for was also from a machine for which the security group was open in the database.